# template containing directive can't set with value from scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to set values in scope (in my case from a service) and then use them in a template.

The commented out template line shows the values I expect, but the uncommented one does not work as expected. I have removed some attributes from ng-dropdown-multiselct for readability. If I set the values manually the ng-dropdown-multiselect works as expected so I know the markup is correct, just can't get the values set.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
  .directive('myFilter', [function () {
    return {
      //template: '<div>{{ PreparersCustomTexts }}</div>',
      template: '<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" translation-texts="PreparersCustomTexts"></div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope:'=',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.PreparersCustomTexts = { buttonDefaultText: 'Select Preparers' };

      }
    };
  }])
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in your html.  You should add that to your question.

In the mean time, here's sample code using your directive, and a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4GSH0R0RWmLcAbVPp0Go?p=preview) with your directive successfully grabbing scope values for either template definition!

```js
angular.module('plunker', [])
.directive('myFilter', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div>{{ PreparersCustomTexts }}</div>',
      //template: '<div translation-texts="PreparersCustomTexts">test</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope:'=',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.PreparersCustomTexts = { buttonDefaultText: 'Select Preparers' };

      }
    };
  })
  ;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker">
    <div>
      <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
      <my-Filter></my-Filter>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: If I change the attribute translation-texts to exactly what is set in the scope it works. I should clarify the problem is happening when using ng-dropdown-multiselect directive.


`
//this works
translation-texts="{ buttonDefaultText: \'Select Preparers\' }"

//this does not work
translation-texts="PreparersCustomTexts"
`


Thanks!